# git add: add all files named 'pom.xml', either in same, or any child directory

Tags: linux, git

I want to create a general Jenkins script that changes stuff in the project, which has to be committed. All changed files are `pom.xml` files. In some cases, we are talking about multi-module projects, but it isn't always the case. Either way, I want to stage every pom.xml-s in the given git repo.

The command I wanted to use is `git add '**/pom.xml'`, but it doesn't stage the pom.xml in the repo root. What's worse is if the project is not a multi-module one, it throws an error, because it can't find any pom.xml-s.

I tried `git add pom.xml '**/pom.xml'`, but it returns with the same error: `fatal: pathspec '**/pom.xml' did not match any files`

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 3):

The command has become from `git add '**/pom.xml'` to `find . -name 'pom.xml' | xargs git add` and it works now

Comment: `git add pom.xml && git add '**/pom.xml'`; `find . -name 'pom.xml' -exec git add '{}' \+`

Comment: what does this do?